# d3.js running slower once minified

Tags: javascript, d3.js, minify

I've just noticed the weirdest thing. I was having performance issue with an customization of the D3 co-occurence matrix representation. I have simply changed the mouseover to darken the color of the cells when overed, and it was producing important slowdowns.

I decided to try run with the un-minified version to get a better understanding of the source of the problem and SURPRISE! The slowdown disappeared completely. Of course I used the same version of D3, and the minification provided in the release package.

Note: my investigation show that it was the .style() attribute that was producing the slowdown. From time to time the operation was taking a very important amount of time, up to 300ms, as if a huge step of garbage collection or something similar kicked in.

I would be very interested by any sort of explanation !

Comment: Are you sure that you were using the same D3 versions for normal and minified?

Comment: yeah, both came from the same release zip file downloaded on the official d3js.org. You have no likely explanation ?

Comment: Just minifying the source shouldn't cause this.